# Getting a total number of checkins for a Yelp venue via API

Tags: api, checkin, yelp

I guess the title is quite self-describing.

Is there a way to determine the total count of check-ins that a Yelp business has using their API?

I don't seem to be able to find it in their API docs, and the actual API responses don't give any hints either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently, no. The full public API is documented at http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation - if you don't see a field listed in the available fields there, it's not available for public consumption.